# Same RELEASE Certificate Fingerprint on two Android Studio installations?

Tags: android-studio

I'm using Android Studio 2.2.1 on two different machines. I need the Release Certificate Fingerprint to be the same on both machines. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I finally solve the issue.

1. Copy your debug.keystore from your C:\Users\user.android from the first instalation an take it to the same location in the second instalation. This is for the DEBUG CERTIFICATE.
2. Copy your app-release.jks from where you saved this in the first instalation an take it to the same location in the second instalation. This is for the RELEASE CERTIFICATE.